# Trying to use protobuf-net with preallocated objects

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

TLDR; I'm trying to Serialize / Deserialize all member values of an object graph where the objects are preallocated

```
[ProtoContract]
class Node {
    [ProtoMember(1)] int data;
    [ProtoMember(2)] string moreData;
    [ProtoMember(3)] Node otherNodeInSameGraph;
    LargeData thisComesFromAnotherSourceAndIsPreallocated;
}

[ProtoContract]
class Graph {
    [ProtoMember(1)] List<Node> allNodesInGraph;
}
```

My goal is to be able to save a graph, and load the graph back, where all Nodes have already been allocated (in order to handle `Node.thisComesFromAnotherSourceAndIsPreallocated`).

---

Full version (Sorry for the wall of text):

I'm trying to use protobuf-net to implement save games in a Unity game. I can serialize standalone classes just fine, but I'm running into some issues when it comes to classes deriving from Unity's built-in MonoBehaviour.

Basically, Unity requires that *it* creates any of these objects. Normally that's fine, as they're part of a large, pre-constructed object graph (containing graphics & other stuff)

```
public class MonoBehaviour : Behaviour {
    public MonoBehaviour() { 
        throw new DontDoThisException (
            "You should never allocate monobehaviours yourself, but let Unity do it"
        ); 
    }
}
```

In my game, I have something that can be simplified as a bunch of Monsters, attacking each other. Let's model this as this

```
[ProtoContract]
class Monster : MonoBehaviour {
    [ProtoMember(2)] public int health;
    [ProtoMember(3)] public Monster whoAmITargetting;
}
```

And I have a SaveManager, that knows about all Monsters in my game.

```
public SaveManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static List<Monster> allMonsters;
}
```

The rub comes when I try to use this with Protobuf-net. Protobuf-net would like to instantiate these objects for me (which normally is fine). The thing is that I already have all the monsters existing in the world, and would like to the data into these. This gets more complex as they have pointers to each other.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude (100, typeof (Monster))]
class SavableBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    [ProtoMember(1)] public long guid;    // I can guarantee that these are unique.
}

[ProtoContract]
class Monster : SavableBehaviour {
    // as above
}
```

Now, my goal is to serialize `Monster.whoAmITargetting` as just the GUID. When I Deserialize, I would look up the GUI in a global list and assign the object.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SerializableSurrogate
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] int saveID { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator SerializableSurrogate (SavableComponent comp)
    {
        return 
            comp != null 
            ? new SerializableSurrogate { saveID = comp.saveID } 
            : null;
    }

    public static implicit operator SavableComponent (SerializableSurrogate surr)
    {
        return SaveManager.allMonsters.Find (i=>i.guid == surr.saveID);
    }
}
```

This works (I think). I can see the surrogate being called like I expect them to. There is a problem, however. When the I try to save `SaveManager.allMonsters`, the surrogate also gets activated, meaning I save only the GUIDs, and none of the other variables.

Is there some novel approach I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hugely familiar with unity, but I suspect there are a few options here; the first thing to try is `Serializer.Merge` rather than `Serializer.Deserialize`. If you are using the `TypeModel` API, this is `Deserialize` but passing in a pre-existing instance.

The other option is to use a custom factory; from memory, this option is only currently available by touching the `RuntimeTypeModel` instance (I should make it available via attributes), but this acts as a static method (optionally taking in the serialization-context) that creates instances: that can do whatever you like, including (presumably) asking unity.

---

With the comments below to clarify things, my advice changes to the age-old: serialize the data; don't serialize the implementation. The `MonoBehaviour` class, along with all the rules about it, is *implementation*. It would be far preferable to serialize something that was not in any way related to that - a simple DTO model (perhaps very basic, just your guids etc) - and simply map to/from the DTO model before/after serialization. This adds a little code, but it solves virtually every "but there are constraints on what my model can do" problem, and also isolates you from versioning/refactoring concerns (it won't matter if you change to a completely different engine; your DTO model is unaffected by changes to the model, so all you need to do is keep the *mapping* code up to date; your DTO stays largely unchanged).

Comment: Thanks your time. In Unity, you usually load (or recycle) objects in a pre-configured state (think: Here is a monster with all graphics, etc). In there would be a small(ish) object (the Monster class) that has all the game-specific logic. What I'm trying to do is loading a world with 20 monsters already in it (as well as a ton of other stuff), and <i>then</i> patch in the monsters data. Some of these monsters are different, so I can't just get _a_ monster, I need the correct one. I could use surrogates to save and load, but I have some 50-100 different classes I need to do this with...

Comment: I've tried using a factory, but the thing is that I need to be able to find the Monster with the right ID in my world. For the factory, the callback I'm looking for is something like  `public static Foo CreateFoo(int ID) { }`
I've looked at Merge, but I'm still stuck on saving an ID to objects when I have a reference, vs. going into the object for the root list